# Proving $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{3x^2-x-2}{5x^2+4x+1}=\frac{3}{5}$

Tags: calculus

Prove that: $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{3x^2-x-2}{5x^2+4x+1}=\frac{3}{5}$$

My solution: For all $\varepsilon>0$,$$\left|\frac{3x^2-x-2}{5x^2+4x+1}-\frac{3}{5}\right|<\varepsilon\iff\left|\frac{17x+13}{5(5x^2+4x+1)}\right|<\varepsilon\iff\frac{1}{\varepsilon}<\left|x+\frac{8x^2-33x+5}{17x+13}\right|$$
holds. So it's sufficient to take $N>\max(\frac{1}{\varepsilon}, x_1, x_2)$ where $x_1, x_2$ are roots of $8x^2-33x+5=0$.

i. e. for all $x>N$, we have $\left|\frac{3x^2-x-2}{5x^2+4x+1}-\frac{3}{5}\right|<\varepsilon$

But there is messy calculation in my solution so I want to make it clear. Any good idea?

Answer (score 3):

It is often very helpful with these kinds of problems to first bound the particular function you care about with much simpler functions. For example, in this problem, if $x>0$ then $5x^2 +4x+1 \geqslant 5x^2$, so $$\bigg \vert \frac{17x+13}{5(5x^2+4x+1)} \bigg \vert \leqslant \frac{17x+13}{25x^2}.$$ Moreover, if $x \geqslant 1 > 13/17$ then $$13 \leqslant 13 \cdot \frac{17x}{13}=17x, $$ so $$\bigg \vert \frac{17x+13}{5(5x^2+4x+1)} \bigg \vert \leqslant \frac{17x+17x}{25x^2}=\frac{34}{25x} \leqslant\frac2 x .$$ Thus, for each $\varepsilon >0$, if $x>\max \{ 1, 2/\varepsilon\}$ then $$\bigg \vert \frac{17x+13}{5(5x^2+4x+1)} \bigg \vert  < \varepsilon. $$

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to do this is to factor out the dominant term.

$$\dfrac{3x^2-x-2}{5x^2+4x+1}=\underbrace{\dfrac{3x^2}{5x^2}}_{\to\frac 35}\times\underbrace{\dfrac{1-\overbrace{\frac 1{3x}}^{\to\ 0}-\overbrace{\frac{2}{3x^2}}^{\to\ 0}}{1+\underbrace{\frac{4}{5x}}_{\to\ 0}+\underbrace{\frac 1{5x^2}}_{\to\ 0}}}_{\to\ 1}\to\frac 35$$

Now would you like effectively to work in epsilon-delta, you were on the right track calculating $\left|\dfrac{17x+13}{25x^2+20x+5}\right|$, but then went astray trying to introduce $\frac 1\varepsilon$.

Notice that $x\to+\infty$ so we can consider $x\gg 1$, but let just assume $x>1$

In particular $13x>13$ which allows you to bound:

$$|17x+13|=17x+13<17x+13x<30x$$

*Note: we can get rid of absolute values since $x>1>0$.*

Now for the denominator: $$25x^2+\underbrace{20x+5}_{>25>0}>25x^2$$

In the end $$\Bigg|f(x)-\frac 35\Bigg|<\frac{30x}{25x^2}<\underbrace{\frac{30}{25}}_{<2}\times\frac 1x<\frac 2x\to 0$$

You van take $x>\max(\frac 2\varepsilon,1)$ now to conclude your proof. We take the max because we need both conditions:

- $x>1$ which allowed us to bound the numerator and denominator
- $x>\frac 2\varepsilon$ which ensures $\frac 2x<\varepsilon$